# Duplicate up-vote allowed on questions using review page

Tags: bug, questions, voting, review

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to the review page, and find a question.
2. Open that question by clicking on the question link, click the "upvote" button.
3. Use your browser's back button to get back to the review page
4. Click the "Review Question" link, and click the upvote button that now appears.

There you go, 2 upvotes allowed, from the same account.

Comment: I guess the team needs to know on which question you did this. And: how can *you* tell the other vote was not from some other user? (I am 100% sure the validation is done on the server side, and cannot imagine there's duplicate code handling this...)

Comment: First time was an accident, but I tested it a second time. I don't want to abuse the system, so I made sure I picked a decent question to do it on, but both votes retained. I gave the steps to replicate it above. It'll work on any question.

Comment: A UI 'bug', perhaps, but if you re-open the question you'll notice only one vote sticking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite. If you refresh the page from step two you will see only one (first) upvote.

So, it seems that there are no duplicate votes applied. However, there still is a small UX issue when you are shown an extra upvote in step 4.

By the way, this was insanely difficult to reproduce. I could barely find a question worthy of an upvote (even for experimental purposes) on review page. I even ended up with close-voting a few.

Comment: Ah, if I visit the question itself again the one vote does go back, its just shown as 2 votes on the review page, and I agree, hunting the good questions down isn't always easy! Still a UI bug, though minor.

Comment: @BrianDeragon: Which is probably why it took so long until someone finally found that bug :D

Answer (score 3):

```
5. Visit the question again, only one vote sticks.
```